# Rendering graph generated by MakeGraph using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, graph

The arcpy [MakeGraph_management](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000005t000000) tool suggests that a graph is stored via an in_memory representation that can be either:

1. added to the host app or
2. saved using [SaveGraph_management](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Save_Graph/00170000005v000000/).

The graph appears to be stored in a manner similar to an in_memory layer, e.g. `in_memory/<name>.grf`.

In the case of an in_memory layer, it is possible to add the layer to the map (ToC).  I can not find documentation describing how to programmatically add the `.grf` (an instance of the arcpy.Graph() class) to the map.  I am interested in having the graph remain interactive - so I am not using arcpy.mapping to add the graph to a map element.

Does anyone have documentation that describes how to render the graph generated by MakeGraph?

Answer (score 1):

As [commented by @user681](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109140/rendering-graph-generated-by-makegraph-using-arcpy#comment154156_109140):

> you can't, there is no ability, use matplotlib particularly if you
>   want dynamic graphs

Alternatively, you could investigate ArcGIS Pro and/or submit an ArcGIS Idea to get ArcPy enhanced.